# Infinite family of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $I$ be an infinite set. I want to find an infinite family of open subsets $U_i\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $$\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i = \{0\}.$$

Does such a family of sets exist?

Comment: You'll have a bit of a problem if $I$ is finite.

Comment: As I said, $I$ is any set, which could be infinite.

Comment: If $I$ is any set, it might be finite, and then you'll have a problem. Please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, I just need one example (in this case we can suppose $I$ is finite).

Comment: So fix your question! (You can't suppose $I$ is finite.)

Comment: @MichaelHowlard what do you mean by "in this case we can suppose $I$ is finite", exactly? I wrote one example for some $I$ below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking just for some example of $I$, take $I = \mathbb N $ and $U_n=\left\{z \in \mathbb C \mid |z| < \frac{1}{n}\right\}$.

Comment: If $I$ is uncountable, you can just take all but a countable number being the whole plane, and the other ones as above, and as mentioned above, if $I$ is finite you have a big problem (finite intersection of open sets is open, and a singleton is not open).

Comment: If we offset this by some $a\in\mathbb{C}$, say $$U_n = \left\{z\in\mathbb{C} \,\,\colon\,\, \lvert z-a\rvert<\frac{1}{n}\right\}.$$ Would this still have a zero intersection?

Comment: The center of my disks is always $0$, the center of your disks is always $a$. Can you see what the intersection is going to be if you shrink the disks?

Comment: $a$? However this actually works for what I need it for! (If this is true in that case)

Comment: The intersection is, indeed, $\{a\}$.